# CakePHP - how to link html css helper to a different folder

Tags: cakephp

Currently I'm using using this to load in css in my CakePHP project.

```
echo $this->Html->css('jquery-ui',null,array('inline' => false));
```

That is assuming that I'm putting my css file in a css folder.
However, I'm now thinking about moving my css that is needed for js libraries to the js folder instead. (i.e in js/lib/jquery-ui.js AND js/lib/jquery-ui.css). That way I don't have to keep track of 2 folders with the same structure.

How can I change where CakePHP's css helper to point to a different folder?
Or is that not a good practice what I'm trying to do. (i.e moving the plugin css to live in the same folder as the js)

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 10):

From [the API](http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/source-class-HtmlHelper.html#375-476):

> If `$path` is prefixed with '/', the path will be relative to the webroot of your application. Otherwise, the path will be relative to your CSS path

So you'd do:

```
echo $this->Html->css('/js/lib/jquery-ui',null,array('inline' => false));
```