# Relative path to CSS file?

Tags: cakephp

Is there a way to get CakePHP's css method to emit a path relative to the current document?

I.e., using this code:

```
$this->Html->css('tutorial');
```

Instead of generating

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Tutorial/css/tutorial.css" />
```

it would instead generate something like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/tutorial.css" />
```

I know this is goofy, but I'm looking to create something that can be retrieved using wget, then viewed offline. I've told CakePHP to handle .html extensions (using Router::parseExtensions('html');), then set up routes to the controller/action that look like a directory structure for static HTML files.  I'm looking for a way to generate a URL that's relative to the page so that when I save the files (using wget) they'll still work when read from the hard drive.

**As thaJeztah points out below**, this isn't possible in CakePHP.  Because CakePHP is abstractly mapping URLs to controllers & actions it does't really have any notion of 'serving a file' anymore (except in the /pages/subdirs, etc) so the only thing that makes sense for CakePHP is to provide a URL that starts at the root & works down to the .CSS files.  (Much thanks to thaJeztah for pointing this out!)

Comment: They're both relative paths.

Comment: Does css("../../tutorial") work ?

Comment: Huh.  URLs starting with "/" are, apparently, relative.  I was thinking of "relative to the current document"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [API](http://api.cakephp.org/2.0/class-HtmlHelper.html#method-HtmlHelpercss)

> If $path is prefixed with '/', the path will be relative to the webroot of your application. Otherwise, the path will be relative to your CSS path

So you could start the path with a `/` and then point from there, that way you don't need to go backwards in directories.

Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370159/cakephp-how-to-link-html-css-helper-to-a-different-folder) for pointing this out

Comment: I'm looking for a path relative to the document (instead of being relative to the webroot folder, or the CSS path)

Comment: I understand, but my thinking was that you can just type out the path relative to the webroot instead of having to go back in directories from the CSS folder

Comment: I know this is goofy, but I'm looking to create something that can be retrieved using wget, then viewed offline.  So it needs to be relative to the document.

Comment: Also - thank you for the suggestion!  I greatly appreciate your help with this! :)

Comment: The reason for using 'absolute' paths (i.e. relative to the 'root') is that otherwise the CSS paths would become invalid if you added more parameters to your URL, for example, for this request ; `/controller/action/1` the path should be `../../css/styles.css`. However, for this request: `/controller/action/1/page:2/sort:name/`, the path to the CSS would have to be `../../../../../css/styles.css`. Using 'absolute' URLs is therefore the preferred way, making sure that the paths always work properly

Comment: @thaJeztah Are you hinting that my answer is invalid or correct? I'm confused by your comment

Comment: No, but trying to explain the reasoning behind CakePHP using absolute paths for CSS and JavaScript assets to the OP. I was writing my comment while OP added his explanation for offline use :)

Comment: @MikeTheTall maybe you should append the explanation/reasoning behind your question to your original question (use the [edit] link). People may have other suggestions as well, also it will make clear what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @thaJeztah Neither of these are absolute paths, not literally nor in quotes; both formats are specifically, literally (no quotes, nothing), _relative_ paths.

Answer (score 0):

As a side-note, you can actually get a copy of a website using the "wget" command.  (There's even a nice "Visual WGet" for Windows, which presents a friendly GUI for all the command line options).  wget will download all the files and (if you use the -k / --convert-links option) will fix up all the links to be relative (to each document) so that they work offline.

It's important to **wait till wget completely finishes**, as wget does this weird two-phase thing where it FIRST gets all the files and THEN goes back and fixes up the links